# Use PySpark Dataframe column in another spark sql query

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a situation where I'm trying to query a table and use the result (dataframe) from that query as IN clause of another query.

From the first query I have the dataframe below:

```
+-----------------+
|key              |
+-----------------+
|   10000000000004|
|   10000000000003|
|   10000000000008|
|   10000000000009|
|   10000000000007|
|   10000000000006|
|   10000000000010|
|   10000000000002|
+-----------------+
```

And now I want to run a query like the one below using the values of that dataframe dynamically instead of hard coding the values:

```
spark.sql("""select country from table1 where key in (10000000000004, 10000000000003, 10000000000008, 10000000000009, 10000000000007, 10000000000006, 10000000000010, 10000000000002)""").show()
```

I tried the following, however it didn't work:

```
df = spark.sql("""select key from table0 """)
a = df.select("key").collect()
spark.sql("""select country from table1 where key in ({0})""".format(a)).show()
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: This should be done using `join`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an (inner) join between two data frames to get the countries you would like. See my example:

```
# Create a list of countries with Id's
countries = [('Netherlands', 1), ('France', 2), ('Germany', 3), ('Belgium', 4)]

# Create a list of Ids
numbers = [(1,), (2,)]  

# Create two data frames
df_countries = spark.createDataFrame(countries, ['CountryName', 'Id'])
df_numbers = spark.createDataFrame(numbers, ['Id'])
```

The data frames look like the following:

```
df_countries:

+-----------+---+
|CountryName| Id| 
+-----------+---+
|Netherlands|  1|
|     France|  2|
|    Germany|  3|
|    Belgium|  4|
+-----------+---+

df_numbers:
+---+
| Id|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
+---+
```

You can join them as follows:

```
countries.join(numbers, on='Id', how='inner')
```

Resulting in:

```
+---+-----------+
| Id|CountryName|
+---+-----------+
|  1|Netherlands|
|  2|     France|
+---+-----------+
```

Hope that clears things up!

Comment: Join is the correct way. But join is slower than direct query. For 1 or 2 values in the where condition we can better extract them and use them in the query instead of join a big dataset